# Does this quantity have a name in statistics?

Tags: statistics, reference-request

I'm interested to know if there is some known statistical context for the following quantity $Q$:

$$Q = \text{Mean} + \sqrt{(n-1)\cdot\text{Variance}}$$

where as usual

$$\text{Mean} = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n x_k}n$$

$$\text{Variance} =\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k - \text{Mean})^2}n$$

My co-worker says that $Q$ looks vaguely familiar from somewhere.

Is $Q$ a known statistical quantity?

Comment: If you consider the other definition of variance (with $n-1$ in the denominator instead of $n$), then you can rewrite $Q$ as $Mean + \sqrt{\sum (x_k - Mean)^2}$ but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Unfortunately, I actually want the Q as defined above.  However, it is likely that my friend was vaguely familiar with the expression because he was using the other definition of variance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RHS is the upper bound of the so-called "Samuelson" or "Lagguerre-Samuelson" inequality. The inequality states that in any sample, all elements of the sample cannot be further away from the sample mean than $\sqrt{n-1}$ standard deviations (or sqrted variances).
Namely, for any sample $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ we have

$$ \forall \,i \qquad \text{Mean}-\sqrt{(n-1)\cdot Variance} \le x_i \le \text{Mean} +   \sqrt{(n-1)\cdot Variance}\;=Q$$

See [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuelson%27s_inequality).

Comment: Thanks, you nailed it.  I think there should be a name for this inequality more reflective of the title of Samuelson's 1968 paper "How deviant can you be?".  (Who could not want to cite a paper with such a title?)